# Element used for input type file retaining hover state after click

Tags: html, css

I created a simple input type file placeholder like this:

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.image .first {
  display: none;
}
.image .second {
  display: block;
}
.image:hover .first {
  display: block;
}
.image:hover .second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <input type="file" id="file-input" />
  <label for="file-input">
    <div class="first" style="height: 40px;background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="second" style="height: 40px;background-color: blue;"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Whenever, I hover over the `.image` element I need to display `.first` and hide `.second`. This is happening successfully if I don't click on the `file-input` label.

However, when click on `file-input` label, the hover state persists(the red div shows) even after navigating away.

Here's a [pen.](http://codepen.io/tarun-dugar/pen/GjvKLN)

Comment: which browser are you testing in?

Comment: Also fine in chrome

Comment: its chrome, also, linger for about 1-2 sec after you click.

Comment: I think OP is moving the cursor outside the browse file window and in turn having it go red, but that is the closest I can get to the error. Mac Chrome here.